# String constants in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

In Python

```
>>> import string
>>> string.uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

or

```
>>> string.digits
'0123456789'
```

Is there a way to use a [string constant](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-constants) in Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any string constants like that in Ruby, but you could specify a range of characters to achieve the same thing:

```
>> ('A'..'Z').to_a.join("")
=> "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
>> ('0'..'9').to_a.join("")
=> "0123456789"
```

Answer (score 3):

There are nothing like that in ruby. But it's easy to do this

```
class String

  def self.uppercase
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  end

  def self.digits
    '0123456789'
  end
end
```

After you can call it

```
String.uppercase
String.digits
```